# What is the size of sizeof(vector)? C++

Tags: c++, vector

So the user inputs values within the for loop and the vector pushes it back, creating its own index. The problem arises in the second for loop, I think it has to do something with `sizeof(v)/sizeof(vector)`.

```
 vector<int> v;

 for (int i; cin >> i;)
 {
    v.push_back(i);
    cout << v.size() << endl;
 }

 for (int i =0; i < sizeof(v)/sizeof(vector); i++)
 {
    cout << v[i] << endl;
 }
```

How will I determine the size of the vector after entering values? 
(I'm quite new to C++ so If I have made a stupid mistake, I apologize)

Comment: use iterator: `for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(), ++it) { ... }`

Comment: An improvement would be `for (auto i : v ) cout << i << endl;`

Comment: Please use range based for loop: `for(auto& x : v)`. To get size of different containers (including c-arrays) use `std::size(container)`. The pattern `sizeof(v[0])/sizeof(v)` makes seance only when using pure `C` on C-arrays only.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `vector::size()` method: `i < v.size()`.

The `sizeof` operator returns the size in bytes of the object or expression at compile time, which is constant for a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5):

> How will I determine the size of the vector after entering values?

v.size() is the number of elements in v.  Thus, 
another style for the second loop, which is easy to understand

```
for (int i=0; i<v.size(); ++i)
```

---

A different aspect of the 'size' function you might find interesting: 
on Ubuntu 15.10, g++ 5.2.1,

Using a 32 byte class UI224, the sizeof(UI224) reports 32 (as expected)

Note that

```
sizeof(std::vector<UI224>)  with    0 elements reports 24
sizeof(std::vector<UI224>)  with   10 elements reports 24
sizeof(std::vector<UI224>)  with  100 elements reports 24
sizeof(std::vector<UI224>)  with 1000 elements reports 24
```

Note also, that

```
sizeof(std::vector<uint8_t> with    0 elements reports 24
```

(update)

Thus, in your line

```
for (int i =0; i < sizeof(v) / sizeof(vector); i++)
                   ^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

the 2 values being divided are probably not what you are expecting.

Answer (score 3):

http://cppreference.com is a great site to look-up member functions of STL containers.

That being said you are looking for the `vector::size()` member function.

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
   cout << v[i] << endl;
}
```

If you have at your disposal a compiler that supports C++11 onwards you can use the new [range based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for(auto i : v) 
{
   cout << i << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `std::vector` is a class. It's not the actual data, but a class that manages it.

Use `std::vector.size()` to get the size of the actual data.

Coliru example:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de0bffb1f4d8c836