# Why is the vector subscript out of range?

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, addition, accumulate

I'm trying to code this really simple addition program for practice.

It takes in a list of inputs and stores it in a vector. Then it grabs each consecutive element out of the vector and sums it up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> i;

    int input;
    int sum = 0;
    int y = 0;

    while (std::cin >> input && input != 0000) {
        i.push_back(input);

    }

    for (y; y < sizeof(i); y++) {

        sum = sum + i[y];
    }
    std::cout << sum;
}
```

However, when I compile and run the program it works fine up until the for loop starts running and then the compiler stops and spits out the message that the vector subscript is out of range?

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `i.size()` not `sizeof(i)` is what you want.

Comment: @Mansoor thank you so much, it worked but can I ask what the difference is?

Comment: There is a similar answer available here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034849/what-is-the-size-of-sizeofvector-c#:~:text=Use%20the%20vector%3A%3Asize,for%20a%20std%3A%3Avector%20.

Comment: `i.size()` is the number of entries in the vector, `sizeof(i)` is the size of the `vector` object, containing probably some pointers to the dynamic allocated memory, so, completely unrelated to the number of entries in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the size of sizeof(vector)? C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034849/what-is-the-size-of-sizeofvector-c)

Comment: There are so many more problems with this code, but since this isn't the code review site, I'll just suggest you consider using [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)`(i.begin(), i.end(), 0)` instead of writing that loop at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to loop through the vector, you need to check how many elements it has using `i.size()`:

```
for (y; y < i.size(); y++) 
{
    sum = sum + i[y];
}
```

This is the canonical use case for range-based for-loops:

```
for(const auto& elem : i)
    sum += elem;
```

Or better still use the STL algorithms:

```
#include <numeric>

const auto sum = std::accumulate(i.begin(), i.end(), 0.0);
```

Using `sizeof` gives you the compile-time size of the vector, which refers only to the house-keeping stuff like its size, capacity and data pointer, not the data itself.

Comment: Nice explanation of `sizeof`.